# Angular: Same id attribute in multiple components

Tags: angular

I just figured out that if we use same `id` attribute for HTML elements in multiple components and if the components are rendered together in the view, the `id` gets repeated in the `DOM`.

For example, consider following scenario:

```
//hello.component.html
<p id="greet">Hello</p>

//welcome.component.html
 <p id="greet">welcome</p>

//app.component.html
<app-hello></app-hello>
<app-welcome></app-welcome>
```

Considering `app-hello`, `app-welcome` as selectors for `hello` and `welcome` components respectively, when they are rendered in `app` component, the `id` attribute inside them will get repeated which has same value. So, this will break the `W3C` standard for the `id`, which states that the `id` attribute value should be unique throughout the `DOM`.

As components are said to be indepenedent, encapsulated piece of UI, I don't think it will be desirable to verify if the `id` attributes of elements in all components are unique while implementing components.

So, what should be the approach in this case to maintain unique `id` attribute? The snippets are based on Angular, but I think the question will be applicable for all component based frameworks like React, Vue, etc.

Comment: Don't use IDs when it's not necessary, or use dynamically generated IDs, or adopt a naming convention that prevents clashes, or just be careful, or don't care because the browser won't crash for duplicated IDs anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet is it correct to say we no longer need to use Id because we can use angular to query any element and just classes for styling ?

Comment: For the most part, yes. IDs are still necessary to associate labels with form inputs (or selects, or textareas). And they're very helpful for automated tests.

Answer (score 1):

In our app we  don't set the Id attribute for elements in case we want to set a theme we use a css classes and if we want to get a reference of element we use template reference to get that element or other angular way to query an elemnts from the template.

```html
 <p #greet>Hello</p>
```

component

```js
@ViewChild('greet' , {static:true}) greetElemnt:ElementRef;

ngOnInit(){

console.log(this.greetElemnt.nativeElement)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use id's inside reusable components. It's up to the consumer of these components to assign (or not assign) id's to the component instances.

In case you need to relate t css, use classes instead of id's.

For example:

```
//hello.component.html
<p class="hello_greet">Hello</p>

//welcome.component.html
<p class="welcome_greet">welcome</p>

//app.component.html
<app-hello id="hello"></app-hello>
<app-welcome id="welcome"></app-welcome>
```